# Parallax Slider in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, parallax

I am developing a website in Twitter bootstrap but there is no option to use another slider rather than built-in carousel slider.

Please tell me is there any solution to add Parallax content slider in twitter bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

There are no parallax features in Bootstrap but you can use any parallax slider plugin you want and it shouldn't conflict with Bootstrap.

Comment: Please tell me any good Parallax slider.
It should be responsive and can move background and content.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the current jQuery UI Bootstrap :

http://addyosmani.github.com/jquery-ui-bootstrap/